# Can i launch the system PIN authentication from within an app?

Tags: android

Is it possible to create an authentication from within my app that will validate the user with his device lock PIN? Any intent mechanism or something like that which will prompt the user for keying in his PIN code?

I have seen the `DevicePolicyManager`, but I was unable to come up with. Anything conclusive?

Comment: After some searching I couldn't find anything you're looking for. I highly doubt it's possible. Besides that, I would strongly advise to not use this method for authentication in an app, considering security issues.

Answer (score 4):

Began from Android 5.0, you can use **[KeyguardManager.createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/KeyguardManager.html#createConfirmDeviceCredentialIntent(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))**

This method will create an Intent, which can be used to start system authentication(pin/pattern/password).

For more information, refer [doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#confirm-credential) and [Confirm Credential sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConfirmCredential).