# How can I prompt the user of an Android app to enter their phone password/pin/fingerprint for authentication before accessing settings?

Tags: android

I am making an app and I want part of the app's settings to be "secure" or in other words ensure that the person accessing them knows the phone's password. I could write my own password code and implement that easy enough but I don't want to and it would probably have security issues. So my question is: is it possible to ask the android system to prompt the user for their pin/password before switching activities or running code?

Comment: This should help https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-add-fingerprint-authentication/

Comment: Thank you, I saw that but it doesn't fully solve my problem. What if a phone does not have a fingerprint reader?

Comment: Then this should help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695720/can-i-launch-the-system-pin-authentication-from-within-an-app

Comment: This appears to be what I am looking for, you should reply to the question as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Comment: I can't post this as answer as it will be a link only answer